# UIButton doesn't work in child view controller

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit, viewcontroller, childviewcontroller

UIButton gestures doesn't recognize in child view controller.
UIButton add targer work (button get target action)
User interaction is turned on everywhere, button size is okay. I try to set childVC as main, and then all work good, debug view hierarchy said that button view over other elements. IDK where is problem. I can provide more code, just tell me.

Add target code:

```
        view.buttonOfLanguageFromTranslate.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openDetailView(_:)), for: .touchDown)
```

Add child VC code:

```
    let childVC = ChildVC()
    view.addSubview(childVC.view)
    
    self.addChild(childVC)
    childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    
    childVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.childVC = childVC
```

Button initialization:

```
    var button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Title", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.green, for: .selected)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with

```
        childVC.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

(in mainVC)
When i remove it, childVC recognise my tap
and i dont set additional size for childVC, view of childVC is display correct but not childVC. (as i think)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the buttons on the child view controller did not work because I had forgotten to add that view controller as a child to its parent view controller.

In other words, I missed this line:

```
addChild(childVC)
```